# .NET Binary Serialization in QuickGraph 3.6

Tags: c#, .net, graph, artificial-intelligence, quickgraph

For portability reasons, [QuickGraph](https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) 3.6 does not allow .net (4.0) binary serialization. This is necessary when you want to persist large graphs. unfortunately the source code provided by the authors does not compile, so it is impossible to enable the (binary) serialization. As you can see here ([quick graph issue](https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/discussions/436441)) I am not the only one has found this problem.
Does anyone know how to compile the QuickGraph 3.6 source code? Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Diego.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I recompiled the project as a standard library. [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/diegotosato/news-and-recent-highlights/quickgraph36standardnetclasslibrary) my solution.

d

Comment: Thanks for this, but you changed the version number and removed the strong name, which unfortunately breaks cases where this is needed. Do you have the source project you could share as well?